# Simple Cocoa App with ViewController

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit, nsviewcontroller

I am trying to create a custom `NSViewController` and just log something out in `viewDidLoad`.  In iOS, this is very trivial and works fine.  However, when I setup a `contentViewController` on `NSWindow` (which i assume is similar to `RootViewController` in iOS?) it attempt to load it from a nib.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {


   self.ABViewController = [[ABViewController alloc] init];

   self.window.contentViewController = self.ABViewController;


}
```

> 2016-06-28 09:15:42.186 TestApp[32103:33742217] -[NSNib _initWithNibNamed:bundle:options:] could not load the nibName: ABViewController in bundle (null).

What assumptions am I missing about how Cocoa is different from iOS that prevent me from simply setting up a viewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSViewController` doesn't have the same behavior as `UIViewController`, in that it won't automatically know to look for a nib file with the same name as itself. In other words, it won't automatically know to look for the `ABViewController.nib` file.

The simplest way to fix this is just override the `nibName` method in `ABViewController`:

```
@implementation ABViewController

- (NSString *)nibName {
    return NSStringFromClass([self class]);
}

@end
```

Note that using `NSStringFromClass()` is usually better than trying to hard code the string, as this way will survive refactoring.

You can then call `[[ABViewController alloc] init];` like before and `NSViewController`'s default `init` method will get the nib name from your overridden `nibName` method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your program wan't find the file where the view's are defined. You need to do something like this for storyboards:

```
UIStoryboard *sboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardFileName" 
                                             bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle()];
SecondViewController *vc1 = [sboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```